# Regarding Logarithmic of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

$\newcommand{\Log}{\operatorname{Log}}$

In my undergraduate complex analysis textbook, it claims that $$\Log(1+i)^2=2\Log(1+i)$$ I am not sure if this is a misprint or there is actually a way of proving this equality, as I am pretty sure $$\Log((1+i)^2)=2\Log(1+i)$$ and $$\Log((1+i)^2)\neq \Log(1+i)^2$$
as
$$\Log((\sqrt{2}e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}})^2)=2\left(\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)+i\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\neq\left(\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)+i\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^2$$
however, how would you go about to disprove this, if this were not true.

Any hint would be much appreciated

Comment: They probably meant $\Log((1+i)^2)$.  Somewhat similar to how many would write $\Log z^2$ to mean $\Log(z^2)$, but I agree that it is not good, especially when parentheses must be involved, to use such ambiguous notation.  I don't think anyone would actually write $\Log(z)^2$ to mean $\Log(z^2)$, because in this case the parentheses around $z$ in the first expression are pointless.  With $1+i$, the parentheses are needed to group before squaring.